# Img overflowing body element - scrollbar appear

Tags: html, css, image

I hope you are having a good day.
I have created an image which is 1920X1080, exactly like my monitor.

I have also used CSS reset to make sure there is not default margin/padding.
with all that in mind - once I open the document in the browser, a scrollbar appears.
I know I can set the image to width - 100%, but I want to understand why is it happening.

To clarify -
Img is : 1920x1080
Screen size is also 1920X1080
And the img is overflowing, and scrollbar appear

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/style.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="alon.css">
</head>
<body>
   <img src="img-test-1920.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  *, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }
  * { margin:0; padding:0; }

body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your setup changing the image to my monitor's resolution.

I think your problem is one of the following:

- You've set a different scale in your display config. For example, my monitor is 3840 x 2160. But I use it at a 150% scale. Chrome shows the resolution of the chrome window as 2560 x 1440.
- If your Chrome window is not maximized, you might have very thin borders around the window, and this may also depend on the chrome theme you're using. These borders also result in a loss of pixels, thus the scroll bar shows.
- You have accidentally zoomed in on the document without realizing it. Apologies, as this is probably not it, but I had to put it here for future viewers.

Other than that, I have tried the exact same setup but with a 2560 x 1440 image, and no scroll bar appears, under the conditions that, chrome is maximized, and no zoom is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Just because your screen's resolution is 1920x1080px does not mean that your browser window is 1920x1080px as well. Due to the border of your browser it's probably a lot smaller than that, even in full screen mode.
Second to this, there is a difference between device pixels and CSS-Pixels.

https://medium.com/@flik185/understanding-device-resolution-for-web-design-and-development-3bb4a5183478

This link gives you a good overview what the differences are between those kind of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

It happend to you for so many reason.

```
1.If the browsers zoom level is not 100%.

2.You have the resulation like you mentioned but that not means that browsers have to support this resulation .
```

Those probably your answers .